# Google App Engine URI Error: /_ah/xrds

Tags: google-app-engine, openid

In my GAE admin dashboard, everyday I have URI Error below:

```
/_ah/xrds    50     100%
```

The application was written in Java. Authentication type is (Experimental) Federated Login.

I checked the log:

```
"GET /_ah/xrds HTTP/1.0" 404 2107 - - "www.example.com" ms=27 cpu_ms=27
app_engine_release=1.8.0 instance=....
```

How to prevent this error? What is the cause of the URL error?

Thanks